# POSIX semaphore across 32 and 64 bits processes

Tags: c, linux, posix, semaphore, 32bit-64bit

I'm trying to synchronize 2 processes with a semaphore. One process is 32bits, the second is 64bits.
Under windows, I use `CreateSemaphoreA`,  `WaitForSingleObject` and `ReleaseSemaphore` API. It works well.
Under Linux, I use `sem_open`, `sem_wait` and `sem_post`. I face a tricky issue:

64 bits part (compiled with `gcc` with `-pthreads` and `-lrt` options)

```c
sem = sem_open("/my_sem", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0640, 1);
if (sem != SEM_FAILED) {
    int value;
    if (sem_getvalue(sem, &value) < 0)
        printf("Cannot get sem_value: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    else
        printf("sem_value = %d\n", value);
} else
    printf("sem is not valid\n");
}
```

It prints `sem_value = 1` as expected.

Then I run the following code compiled as 32bits executable (using `-m32` additional option):

```c
sem = sem_open("/my_sem", O_RDWR);
if (sem != SEM_FAILED) {
    int value;
    if (sem_getvalue(sem, &value) < 0)
        printf("Cannot get sem_value: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    else
        printf("sem_value = %d\n", value);
} else
    printf("sem is not valid\n");
}
```

It prints `sem_value = 0` !

It occurs on Ubuntu 20.04.

I tried playing with sem_openning flags with no success.

Comment: Assume that it can't be done.  Compile both programs with the same “bittiness”.  If you must try, youʼll have to study the normally opaque types under 32-bit and 64-bit rules and work out whether the types can be made to work the same.  You might have to use the 32-bit definition in the 64-bit code and reimplement the functions so that the code works identically.  Non-trivial; non-portable; unreliable; not recommeded!

Comment: Do you have a reason for doing this or is it just for fun?

Comment: Rational behind my question: I have to make data exchange between 32 bits applications (that cannot be compiled in 64bits) and master application. 
One alternative I see: switch to socket API.

Comment: Issue was "old": https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17980 maybe someone found a work around :-)

Answer (score 0):

Glibc does not seem to consider https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17980 a bug, and as 32-bit is becoming less and less relevant, I don't think they will change their opinion.

Therefore, it seems best to accept that POSIX semaphores will not work between processes of different bitness, and use something else instead, such as:

- Sockets.
- System V semaphores (aka XSI semaphores) via `semget`, `semop` and `semctl`. I guess it should work to use `IPC_PRIVATE` and store the identifier in the shared memory to be protected. Despite the name, this API is highly portable across Unix-likes.
- Direct use of atomics and futex in shared memory. This is probably a poor choice since it is hard to get right, unless you can find a good library that implements it.

Comment: I switched to SysV semaphores. It simply works. :-)